# What is better solutin for emoticons control

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Hello everyone? I'm makin something like a chat app and i want to make сontrol to select emoticons, but i'm not sure which control can behave as in the gif.
I understand that there is no such default control but i though to redefine combobox or contextmenu.

Any ideas or examples?

Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: A normal `ToggleButton` that displays a custom UserControl when pressed? The icons could easily be displayed using an `ItemsControl`

Comment: Looks like a `Popup` with a `UniformGrid` in it to me. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/using-xaml-popup-in-wpf/

Comment: Thanks guys, i think that will work!